# Representation (Notation) of the Design matrix for Linear Regressions

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, matrix, notation

In the section on linear regressions $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbb{X}\beta + \epsilon$, my textbook represents the design matrix as

$\mathbb{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{x}_{1}^T \\
    \vdots \\
    \mathbf{x}_{n}^T \\
\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & \dots & x_{1p} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n1}       & \dots & x_{np}
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$

I realise that the $T$ in the vector means transpose, but since the transpose operator is on each individual element $\mathbf{x}$ rather than the entire vector itself, what is its function here? Comparing the vector and the matrix, it seems like the transpose operator is doing nothing here; the matrix looks as it would were the $T$ not present. Or am I misunderstanding something?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $\mathbf{x}_i$ is a $p \times 1$ matrix:
$$
\mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}{x_{11} \\ \ \ \vdots \\ x_{1p}}\end{bmatrix},
\ldots,\
\mathbf{x}_n = \begin{bmatrix}{x_{n1} \\ \ \ \vdots \\ x_{np}}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So each $\mathbf{x}_i^T$ is a $1 \times p$ matrix:
$$
\mathbf{x}_1^T = \begin{bmatrix}{x_{11} \ \ldots \ x_{1p}}\end{bmatrix},
\ldots,\
\mathbf{x}_n^T = \begin{bmatrix}{x_{n1} \ \ldots \ x_{np}}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The notation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{x}_{1}^T \\
    \vdots \\
    \mathbf{x}_{n}^T \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
means that the $1 \times p$ matrices are stacked on top of each other, giving the $n \times p$ matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & \dots & x_{1p} \\
    \vdots & & \vdots \\
    x_{n1}       & \dots & x_{np}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is only about notation. Usually, in textbooks the vector symbol $\boldsymbol{x}$ represents the column vector of dimension $p \times 1$. By using the transpose, you are effectively considering the design matrix of dimension $n \times p$.

Answer (score 1):

The initial notational convention here is that by $\mathbb x$ we mean a *column* vector.

Further, in regression analysis (and in most but not all places/fields), and when using matrix algebra notation we use $\mathbb x_i$ to represent the *observation* vector (i.e. one value from each regressors in the same cross section or time period).

Further, the desing matrix is written as having columns representing each one regressor: the row dimension is the number of observations, and the column dimension is the number of regressors.

Therefore, $\mathbb x_i^T$ represents the full first observation as a row.